# Calculating constants for CRC32 using PCLMULQDQ

Tags: sse, crc32, modular-arithmetic, galois-field

I'm reading through the following paper on how to implement CRC32 efficiently using the PCLMULQDQ instruction introduced in Intel Westmere and AMD Bulldozer:

V. Gopal et al. "Fast CRC Computation for Generic Polynomials Using PCLMULQDQ Instruction." 2009. http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/fast-crc-computation-generic-polynomials-pclmulqdq-paper.pdf

I understand the algorithm, but one thing I'm not sure about is how to calculate the constants $k_i$. For example, they provide the constant values for the IEEE 802.3 polynomial:

- k1 = x^(4*128+64) mod P(x) = 0x8833794C
- k4 = x^128 mod P(x) = 0xE8A45605
- mu = x^64 div P(x) = 0x104D101DF

and so on. I can just use these constants as I only need to support the one polynomial, but I'm interested: how did they calculate those numbers? I can't just use a typical bignum implementation (e.g. the one provided by Python) because the arithmetic must happen in GF(2).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just like regular division, except you exclusive-or instead of subtract.  So start with the most significant 1 in the dividend.  Exclusive-or the dividend by the polynomial, lining up the most significant 1 of the polynomial with that 1 in the dividend to turn it into a zero.  Repeat until you have eliminated all of the 1's above the low *n* bits, where *n* is the order of the polynomial.  The result is the remainder.

Make sure that your polynomial has the high term in the *n+1*<sup>th</sup> bit.  I.e., use `0x104C11DB7`, not `0x4C11DB7`.

If you want the quotient (which you wrote as "div"), then keep track of the positions of the 1's you eliminated.  That set, shifted down by *n*, is the quotient.

Here is how:

```
/* Placed in the public domain by Mark Adler, Jan 18, 2014. */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

/* Polynomial type -- must be an unsigned integer type. */
typedef uintmax_t poly_t;
#define PPOLY PRIxMAX

/* Return x^n mod p(x) over GF(2).  x^deg is the highest power of x in p(x).
   The positions of the bits set in poly represent the remaining powers of x in
   p(x).  In addition, returned in *div are as many of the least significant
   quotient bits as will fit in a poly_t. */
static poly_t xnmodp(unsigned n, poly_t poly, unsigned deg, poly_t *div)
{
    poly_t mod, mask, high;

    if (n < deg) {
        *div = 0;
        return poly;
    }
    mask = ((poly_t)1 << deg) - 1;
    poly &= mask;
    mod = poly;
    *div = 1;
    deg--;
    while (--n > deg) {
        high = (mod >> deg) & 1;
        *div = (*div << 1) | high;  /* quotient bits may be lost off the top */
        mod <<= 1;
        if (high)
            mod ^= poly;
    }
    return mod & mask;
}

/* Compute and show x^n modulo the IEEE 802.3 CRC-32 polynomial.  If d is true,
   also show the low bits of the quotient. */
static void show(unsigned n, int showdiv)
{
    poly_t div;

    printf("x^%u mod p(x) = %#" PPOLY "\n", n, xnmodp(n, 0x4C11DB7, 32, &div));
    if (showdiv)
        printf("x^%u div p(x) = %#" PPOLY "\n", n, div);
}

/* Compute the constants required to use PCLMULQDQ to compute the IEEE 802.3
   32-bit CRC.  These results appear on page 16 of the Intel paper "Fast CRC
   Computation Using PCLMULQDQ Instruction". */
int main(void)
{
    show(4*128+64, 0);
    show(4*128, 0);
    show(128+64, 0);
    show(128, 0);
    show(96, 0);
    show(64, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Is there any shortcut to be had by operating on the polynomials directly (i.e. on pen and paper), instead of on their binary representation?

Comment: No, you'll end up with lots of x^n terms to keep track of.  I think it is easier to keep track of the terms with 1's and 0's when doing it by hand as well.